# Search in listview does not show corresponding item

Tags: android, listview, audio

I'm trying to learn java in android studio, but I find myself in a problem.

In the listview when I search for an item it shows the right match name, but when I click to play it plays another item instead of the searched item.

If they have any solutions using searchview it would be better.
Thank you

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et;
    private ArrayList<String> lstEstados_Encontrados = new ArrayList<String>();

    // variable declaration
    private ListView mainList;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    private final String[] listContent = {
        "NHA", "iisso",
        "Rolezeira", 
    };

    private final int[] resID = {
        R.raw.ne, R.raw.eso,
        R.raw.rolezeira, 
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProcurar);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(listView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

            }
        });

        //Carrega o listview com todos os itens
        mainList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent));

        CarregarEncontrados();

        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
            }

            //Evento acionado quando o usuário teclar algo
            //na caixa de texto "Procurar"
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                CarregarEncontrados();

                //Carrega o listview com os itens encontrados
                mainList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lstEstados_Encontrados));
            }
        });
    }

    public void CarregarEncontrados() {

        int textlength = et.getText().length();

        //Limpa o array com os estados encontrados
        //para poder efetuar nova busca
        lstEstados_Encontrados.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < listContent.length; i++) {
            if (textlength <= listContent[i].length()) {
                //Verifica se existe algum item no array original
                //caso encontre é adicionado no array de encontrados
                if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)listContent[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                    lstEstados_Encontrados.add(listContent[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);// create's
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use position for the selected item, when you search and filter item. this makes you select the wrong item. because, position related to items that show on the current screen.

**my solution :**

set textView in layout for store you object ID in it. then in setOnItemClickListener method get **ID** from your selected item. then select corresponding correct data with selected ID, not position.

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_id"
              android:testSize="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

    ... 
    ...
    ... other element

</LinearLayout >
```

in java code :

```java
mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
         String id=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_id)).getText().toString();
       // playSong(id);

    }
});
```